# Internet Explorer 10 not showing background colour

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Windows 7 with IE10 installed and the user has no background colour/image shown no pages at all.

I can't provide a screenshot as it's a private page, but it's just a normal 'set the background colour to X' type page. Instead the background is white, the text is white with a slight black shadow to it making it just about readable however it looks horrible.

In IE all the 'accessability' options are turned off, including those which set a specific style sheet instead, and the one to limit background colours.

Also turned off is the security option that prohibits loading images on non-secured connections for a secured page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I noticed that the scroll bar at the bottom of the page looked odd as well, knowing that there was no custom scrolling being used on this page I decided to investigate.

It appears if you use the windows 7 theme - 'Windows Basic' it will *stop* rendering background colours in IE.

Why this even happens I do not know, it seems rather stupid to me as IE has it's own accessibility settings, but this appears to be the cause. Setting the theme back to 'Windows 7 basic' instead restored the colour to the page and made everything nice again.